# Não consigo estilizar e centralizar o texto do menu

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde, estou colocando um menu fixo no meu blog, está é a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O texto ao lado do ícone `home` está sem estilo, como faço para estilizar esse texto deixando ele centralizado e com espaçamento entre eles, mudar a cor da fonte e colocar `hover`?

O código é esse.

```
/*---TOP FIXED MENIU BLOGGER --------------*/
#menu_fixo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #ffa233;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
#menu_fixo #centro {
    width: 880px;
    height: 45px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}
#menu_fixo #centro li {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#icone_home {
    background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LkHsu7cfje8/U1UpThxpECI/AAAAAAAAAPc/RMSpYE-raKs/s1600/home.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 45px;
    border-left: solid 1px #FFF;
    border-right: solid 1px #FFF;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#icone_home:hover{
    background: #000 url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LkHsu7cfje8/U1UpThxpECI/AAAAAAAAAPc/RMSpYE-raKs/s1600/home.png)no-repeat center center;
}
#social_fixo {
    width: 180px;
    height: 45px;
    border: solid 0px #000;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
#icone_facebook {
    background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-kOAGPn3Ee_0/U1UpTrO8rLI/AAAAAAAAAPk/7cdUoKYU1W4/s1600/icon_facebook.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#icone_twitter {
    background-image: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LyeRkpB716w/U1UpUunplPI/AAAAAAAAAP4/zki33yOb9B8/s1600/icon_twitter.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#icone_gplus {
    background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E7UGiWMmy-4/U1UpTteTpmI/AAAAAAAAAPg/COkFj9AycMM/s1600/icon_google+.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#icone_youtube {
    background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-YJyJLW221zE/U1UpU1Uh2VI/AAAAAAAAAQA/Pi3e-kBwm0c/s1600/icon_youtube.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#caixa-pesquisa {
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px;
    border: solid 1px #3f3f3f;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: table;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
.campo-pesquisa {
    width: 350px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-style: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.botao-pesquisa {
    border: solid 0px;
    background-image: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-2CosUiZa8Qo/U1UpUa6ryYI/AAAAAAAAAP0/m-e14j6j0x4/s1600/icon_search.jpg);
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
}
button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Código `html`:

```
<div id="menu_fixo">
    <div id="centro">
        <li><a href="LINKDOBLOG"><div id="icone_home"></div></a></li>
        <li><a href=' /'>Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href=' /'>loja virtual</a></li>
        <li><a href=' /'>Contato</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Se puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: Coloca o HTML para saber a classe que está sendo aplicada nele.

Comment: @ricardo não entendi pois eu não manjo muito de códigos.

Comment: Para mudar o CSS de alguma tag vc precisa alterar a classe do CSS que está sendo aplicada a essa tag, se fosse uma div seria assim <div class="minhaclassecss" />. Então precisamos saber qual a classe está sendo aplicada a tag que você quer alterar

Comment: Estou colocando assim: <div id="menu_fixo">
  <div id="centro">
    <li><a href="LINKDOBLOG"><div id="icone_home"></div></a></li><li><a href=' /'>Sobre</a></li>
<li><a href=' /'>loja virtual</a></li>
   <li><a href=' /'>Contato</a></li>

Comment: Coloca isso lá na pergunta, da para formatar, so mandar editar a pergunta.

Comment: Pronto @ricardo obrigada!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom vamos lá.

Antes de centralizar o texto, vamos criar o espaçamento entre eles. Para isso você pode usar a propriedade `padding`, ela irá criar um espaço interno, ou seja, dentro um espaço dentro da própria `li`. O valor fica a seu critério, mas o código seria assim:

```
#menu_fixo #centro li {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;

    /* - código adicionado - */
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px; //valores: cima - direita - baixo - esquerda
}
```

Para que o texto fique todo centralizado, horizontal e verticalmente, você pode usar tanto a propriedade `text-align:center` que irá centralizar horizontalmente, como a propriedade `vertical-align:middle` que, usando junto da propriedade `line:height`, irá centralizar ele verticalmente. Veja:

```
#menu_fixo #centro li {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px; //valores: cima - direita - baixo - esquerda

    /* - código adicionado - */
    height:45px; //valor da altura do seu menu;
    line-height:45px; //mesmo valor, para que mantenha dentro da div
    vertical-align:middle; //para centralizar verticalmente
    text-align:center; //para centralizar horizontalemnte
}
```

Agora, se você deseja um efeito de `:hover`, basta aplicar as propriedades dentro dele, da seguinte maneira:

```
#menu_fixo #centro li:hover {
    //Seu código de manipulação aqui
}
```

Veja este exemplo com o seu código já funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/k5L0gk7z/1/